# How to add a counterless or unnumbered section, then add it to table of contents using LaTex?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, unnumbered-sections

I'm doing some text work on **overleaf-platform** and i just want to know, if there is a way to **add a counterless or unnumbered section,  then add it to table of contents** using normal **LaTex** or featured way of achieving such on the **overleaf-platform** ?

```
\section{My counterless section}
```

Comment: Try `\section*{My counterless section}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By counterless you mean unnumbered? Like with `\section*{My counterless section}`?

Comment: Yes i mean **unnumbered**

Comment: It works but there is an issue with the answer :), the unnumbered section didn't appear in the content anymore, but i do need it ! Is there **any way to add the unnumbered section to the table of contents ?**

Comment: Then you have to add it manually, `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{text} `

Comment: Though perhaps you should tell us what exactly you're doing. Often there are better solutions once we know the problem

Comment: Now i just wanted to add the unnumbered section `\section*{My counterless section}`  to the table of contents ?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{text}` works now, i needed to add it extra at the following line, my bad :).

Comment: Please formulate an answer, so i can mark the answer tohiko or vincent or daleif